# Representação MVC em diagrama de classes UML

Tags: java, mvc, uml

Estou construindo o diagrama de classes do meu projeto e fiquei com uma dúvida em certo ponto.
No projeto eu crio uma instância da minha classe Controller no main e passo a referência (sei que em Java a passagem sempre é por valor, mas quando passamos o objeto estamos passando uma cópia da referência, então em linhas gerais acaba dando no mesmo, na maioria dos casos) dessa instância do Controller para três Menus que fazem parte do View do meu projeto.

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MeuController controller = new MeuController();
        MenuProdutos menuProdutos = new MenuProdutos(controller);
        MenuComprador menuComprador = new MenuComprador(controller);
        MenuCompras menuCompras = new MenuCompras(controller);
        //resto do código
   }
}
```

A partir dai eu chamo diversos métodos desses menus para realização de cadastros, compras vendas e etc. A minha dúvida é: como representar isso em um diagrama de classes? Não posso utilizar uma composição entre a minha classe Principal (que contém o main) e o controller, pois não há uma atributo do tipo controller, apesar de haver uma instância dele no main.
 Além disso, também não tenho certeza de qual seria a relação entre a minha classe principal e as classes `MenuProdutos`, `MenuComprador` e `MenuCompras`. 
Também não tenho certeza de qual seria a relação entre as classes Menu e o controller, pensei que poderia ser uma composição, já que eu tenho atributos do tipo controller em cada uma delas.

Answer (score 2):

Para representar a relação entre Principal e as classes Controller e Menu, você pode utilizar uma seta tracejada com o estereótipo instantiate.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode encontrar mais detalhes sobre o uso de dependência nesse link:
http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html

A relação entre Menu e Controller será uma agregação. Pois o Controller é independente do Menu. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A composição seria usada se o objeto Controller apenas existisse mediante a existência do objeto Menu. Se fosse o caso, o Controller não estaria sendo passado como parâmetro para o Menu. Nesses casos, normalmente quando o Menu fosse destruído, o Controller seria destruído junto.

Você pode encontrar mais detalhes sobre composição e agregação nesse link:
http://imasters.com.br/artigo/18901/uml/uml-composicao-x-agregacao?trace=1519021197&source=single